# Need to share URL along with photos to Facebook using iOS SDK

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am working on an iOS application where I would like to share images from the app to Facebook using the Facebook SDK.  I am able to do this successfully, so this is not an issue.  However, what I would like to do, is include in the dialogue that opens up to share the images, to ALSO include additional text like the name of the app, as well as the app's url.  Unfortunately, I can only find in Facebook's documentation how to do this separately, but I would like to share both in one single step.  How do I do this?

Here is the sample code for sharing photos:

```
  UIImage *img = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

  FBPhotoParams *params = [[FBPhotoParams alloc] init];

  // Note that params.photos can be an array of images.  In this example
  // we only use a single image, wrapped in an array.
  params.photos = @[img];

  [FBDialogs presentShareDialogWithPhotoParams:params
                                   clientState:nil
                                       handler:^(FBAppCall *call,
                                                 NSDictionary *results,
                                                 NSError *error) {
                                         if (error) {
                                           NSLog(@"Error: %@",
                                                 error.description);
                                         } else {
                                           NSLog(@"Success!");
                                         }
                                    }];
```

As for sharing a link, this is the code they provide:

```
    NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://developers.facebook.com/ios"];
    [FBDialogs presentShareDialogWithLink:url 
                              handler:^(FBAppCall *call, NSDictionary *results, NSError *error) {
    if(error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error.description);
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Success!");
    }
}];
```

In order to share images, I am supposed to use the method: `presentShareDialogWithPhotoParams` and when I'm sharing a link, I am to use the method: `presentShareDialogWithLink` Is there a method where I can combine both objects (i.e. array of images, and a link/text)?